# What does: "while( (stuff) ? false : (otherstuff)){}" mean?

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

I have a c++ while loop I'm looking at:

```
while ((stuff) ? false : (otherstuff))
{
  commands;
}
```

And I don't really understand what it's trying to do with the "? false :" part?
Can any one explain what this means please?
I already tried looking it up but I'm not really getting anything helpful.

Comment: Do you know what `?:` operator is?

Comment: It's a convoluted way to say `while(!stuff && otherstuff)`

Comment: no, I don't. I've never used it before.

Answer (score 2):

It's using the [ternary conditional operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C.2B.2B) to effectively perform the check:

```
while (!(stuff) && (otherstuff))
```

If `stuff` is true, then the first option on the ternary is evaluated (evaluating to `false`), if it's false, then it evaluates to otherstuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a really bad way of writing this:

```
while (!stuff && otherstuff) {

}
```